# PHP Countdown timer, when finished +7 days and repeat until certain number has been reached

Tags: php, timer, countdown

So here is what I need to do:

- Get time from database (don't worry about the database stuff for the moment)
- Countdown time in days, hours and minutes
- When countdown has reached 0, add 7 days to countdown along with adding 1 to an episode count
- repeat multiple times until episode count reaches certain number (set by database, again don't worry to much about the database stuff at the moment) then stop countdown and just echo Aired

Basically its going to countdown to the next episode of a TV show's airing time and show what episode number is next, this will carry on until all the episodes have aired.

Here is what I have currently, it works to a degree but will only +7 days/++episode once, after that the countdown will go into negatives. I've tried while loops and some other things but I  haven't had too much luck.

```
$date = "February 12, 2013 5:06 PM";
$date = strtotime($date);
$remaining = $date - time();

$episode = 0;

if ($remaining < 0) {
++$episode;
$remaining = strtotime("+7 day", $date) -time();
}

$days_remaining = floor($remaining / 86400);
$hours_remaining = floor(($remaining % 86400) / 3600);
$mins_remaining = floor(($remaining % 86400 % 3600) / 60);

if ($episode == 3){
 echo "Aired";
} else {
echo "$days_remaining:$hours_remaining:$mins_remaining Ep $episode";
}
```

Any advice is really appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it will go to negative.

After `$remaining` reaches 0, another 7 days are added to it.

```
if ($remaining < 0) { // remaining: less than 0 days
++$episode; // episode becomes 1
$remaining = strtotime("+7 day", $date) -time(); // remaining: less than 7 days
}
```

However, after another 7 days, `$remaining` is still negative and only 7 days are added to it. Since you haven't saved `$episode` in a database, it is still 0 according to the code.

```
$episode = 0; // $episode starts at 0 according to the code
if ($remaining < 0) { // remaining: less than -7 days
++$episode; // episode becomes 1
```

So it continues to count negative and give you `$episode == 1`.

You should do this instead:

```
$date = strtotime("February 12, 2013 5:06 PM");
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $episodes[$i+1] = strtotime("+". 7*$i ." day", $date);
    $remainings[$i+1] = $episodes[$i+1] - time();
}
foreach ($remainings as $key => $remaining) {
    if ($remaining > 0) {
        $episode = $key;
        $days_remaining = floor($remaining / 86400);
        $hours_remaining = floor(($remaining % 86400) / 3600);
        $mins_remaining = floor(($remaining % 86400 % 3600) / 60);
        break;
    }
}
if (!isset($episode)){
    echo "Aired";
} else {
    echo "$days_remaining:$hours_remaining:$mins_remaining Ep $episode";
}
```